# RestSharp - Problems with Nested JSON data

Tags: c#, json, restsharp, xamarin-studio

I've tried other answers with people who had the same issue, but I can't get it to work.  Plus I'm new to this.  Any help is appreciated.

When I run this, my phone data is null.

Here's the JSON data I get back from my service.
{"GetDirectoriesResult":"[{\"id\":1,\"department\":\"Admitting\",\"subdepartment\":\"\",\"phone\":\"555-444-4013\",\"comments\":\"Press 1\"},{\"id\":2,\"department\":\"Ambulatory Surgery Center\",\"subdepartment\":\"\",\"phone\":\"555-444-4013\",\"comments\":\"\"}]"}

My Code

```
    public class PhoneList
    {
//      public string GetDirectoriesResult { get; set; } 
        public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }     //- can't get this working
    }

    public class Phone
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string department { get; set; }
        public string subdepartment { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }
    }


        public IRestResponse<PhoneList> Execute<PhoneList>(RestRequest request) where PhoneList : new()
        {
            PhoneList ro = new PhoneList();

            var client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;

//          var request = new RestRequest();
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddJsonBody(ro);

            IRestResponse<PhoneList> response = client.Execute<PhoneList>(request);
            if (response.ErrorException != null)
            {
                const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
                var Exception = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
                throw Exception;
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Comment: Why some `"`s are escaped and some not? (like `"GetDirectoriesResult"` and `\"id\":`) Check your service, Seems like you do unnecessary manual serializations in your code. In this form, your root object should be like `public class RootObject
{
    public string GetDirectoriesResult { get; set; }
}`  (**`List<Phone> != string`**)

Comment: When i use the public string getdirectoriesresult, getdirectoriesresult = [{"id":1,"department":"Admitting","subdepartment":"","phone":"555-444-4013","comments":"Press 1"},{"id":2,"department":"Ambulatory Surgery Center","subdepartment":"","phone":"555-444-4013","comments":""}]  which i then have to parse again.  Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Of course not, As I said before, your are doing double serialization in your server code. Avoid it. Just return your object.

Comment: thanks. I'll have to figure out what's going on on that side.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'd concur that it's a problem on the server side.

Comment: I checked the server side and I can't figure out what I'm doing to add the 2nd layer.  For now, I'm just doing a second parse on the front end.  I'm under a tight deadline, so I'll have to come back to the server side later.